# how to rename/change jar file name using gradle command line

Tags: gradle

I need to generate jar file name by appending hash value in build/libs folder. I have to pass some argument to do that as per my requirement.

For instance: gradle clean build -Djar.archiveName=Testfile-12634.jar (it is not working)

Currently jar file is generating like "Testfile.jar" , i want to append hash value (-12634) to that jar file but through gradle command only.

Any one please suggest? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to define the archivesBaseName in the `build.gradle` file.@devops

Answer (score 0):

try to define the name in `build.gradle` like this way:

```
project(":dolphin-post:dolphin-post-service") {
    archivesBaseName = "dolphin-post-service"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    bootJar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Start-Class': 'com.dolphin.soa.post.AppStarter'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery"
        implementation project(":dolphin-post:dolphin-post-api")
        api "com.rometools:rome:1.15.0"
    }

}
```

then you can replace the version using your random code like this:

```
def uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

the `archivesBaseName` and `version` will make you custom your own jar name. You can try another way to pass parameter from gradle command:

```
./gradlew build publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository -x test -PpubRepoUrl=https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-releases/
```

and received in `build.gradle` like this:

```
def pubRepoUrl = project.hasProperty('pubRepoUrl') ? pubRepoUrl : "$SnapshotRepo"
```

but you still need to edit your `build.gradle` file to recive the parameter from gradle command.

Comment: can i able to custom jar file name without changes in build.gradle file and just passing build argument(gradle build )?